# не запускается программа на c++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    double x, y, a, с, b, U;
    a = 4.5;
    cout.setf(ios::fixed);
    cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
    cout.precision(2);
    
    for (с = 0; с <= 3.14; с = atan(1) * 4 / 6)
    {
        x = a * sin(с);
        
        for (b = 3; b <= 6; b = b + 1);
        {
            y = b * cos(с);
            if (x < b || y < a) 
                
                U = y + ((x - b) * (int(abs(y - a))) * (a - b));
            else 
                if (U = pow(y + x, 2) + fabs(pow(a, 2)) + b)
                    
            cout << "\n x=" << x << " y=" << y << " a=" << a << " с=" << с << " U=" << U;
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

компилятор выдает ошибки:
main.cpp:34:21: error: expected ‘;’ before string constant
cout « "\n x=" « x « " y=" « y « " a=" « a « " с=" « с « " U=" « U;
^~~~~~~
main.cpp:35:21: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘endl’
cout « endl;
^~~~

при постановке ";" ничего не меняется

Comment: Проверьте вложенный `if`

Comment: перед else стоит ;

Comment: Переменная `c` и сдвиг `<<` какие то неправильные в вашем коде...

Comment: хм.. что нужно тогда изменить?

Comment: уверен,что на нее ругается?

Comment: https://ideone.com/S2y9Sq

Comment: Эх... должно быть два знака меньше `<<` а не кавычки `«`   И `с` похоже русская

Comment: Кавычка вместо сдвига еще куда не шло, но как можно было писать что `c` везде кириллическая????

Comment: понял, пофиксил

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Итак, начнём по порядку:

1. Ваш внешний цикл - бесконечный. Переменная `c` всегда получает одно и тоже значение. Скорее всего нужно так:

```
for (с = 0; с <= 3.14; с += atan(1) * 4 / 6)
```

2. Точка с запятой в конце строки `for (b = 3; b <= 6; b = b + 1);` не нужна. Она является пустым оператором, который и будет выполнять этот цикл. Т.е. ничего.
3. Вот этот код:

```
else 
    if (U = pow(y + x, 2) + fabs(pow(a, 2)) + b)
```

скорее всего должен выглядеть вот так:

```
else 
    U = pow(y + x, 2) + fabs(pow(a, 2)) + b;
```

Если собрать всё вместе, то получим

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double x, y, a, c, b, U;
    a = 4.5;
    
    cout.setf(ios::fixed);
    cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
    cout.precision(2);
    
    for (c = 0; c <= 3.14; c += atan(1) * 4 / 6)
    {
        x = a * sin(c);
        
        for (b = 3; b <= 6; b = b + 1)
        {
            y = b * cos(c);
            if (x < b || y < a) 
                U = y + ((x - b) * (int(abs(y - a))) * (a - b));
            else 
                U = pow(y + x, 2) + fabs(pow(a, 2)) + b;
                    
            cout << "x = " << x << " y = " << y << " a = " << a << " с = " << c << " U = " << U << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: не, мне прямо таки конкретно интересно как так вышло что переменная `c` была набрана кириллицей

Comment: @ДжонниКэтсвилл Скорее всего результат копи-паста.

Comment: @Андрей Галюченко Если Вам помог этот ответ - примите его, поблагодарите автора. Для этого есть галочка слева от ответа.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (U = pow(y + x, 2) + fabs(pow(a, 2)) + b)
```

Где у вас тут проверка?

Comment: так а что проверять?

Comment: А что вы тут хотели проверить?  Ради чего тут стоит `if`?

Comment: И где ,кстати, информация об ошибке компиляции, если она была?

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов, пала жертвой в войне редакций вопроса

Comment: О! Прошу пардону, это мой косяк.